# Как получить нужные данные из JSON?

Tags: php, json

Пытаюсь получить данные из Json, но ничего не получается.

Функция

```
public function getItem($id)
{
    $response = @json_decode($this->request('GET', 'https:// site.ru/ap/my/op?search=' . $id)['body'], true);

    if (isset($response['error'])) {
        throw new Exception($response['error']);
    }

    return new MyItem($response);
  }
```

Отдает

```
var_dump ($items);

object(MyItem)#120 (1) {
["data":protected]=>
array(1) {
[0]=>
array(16) {
  ["dtoType"]=>
  string(7) "partner"
  ["id"]=>
  int(3228933)
  ["userId"]=>
  int(571106)
  ["sellerReward"]=>
  float(180)
  ["createdAt"]=>
  string(24) "2019-08-16T05:18:05.309Z"
  ["status"]=>
  string(8) "APPROVED"
  ["currency"]=>
  string(3) "RUR"
  ["income"]=>
  float(270)
  ["customer"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1118038)
    ["fio"]=>
    string(27) "Валера"
    ["email"]=>
    string(28) "valera111953@mail.ru"
  }
  ["ware"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(178109)
    ["title"]=>
    string(93) "Прокат за месяц!"
    ["type"]=>
    string(7) "DIGITAL"
    ["userId"]=>
    int(571106)
  }
  ["paymentSystem"]=>
  string(4) "visa"
  ["paymentSystemGroup"]=>
  string(10) "creditCard"
  ["total"]=>
  float(550)
  ["ipAddress"]=>
  string(13) "37.71.177.737"
  ["isOneTimeOffer"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["orderType"]=>
  string(9) "WARE_SALE"
  }
 }
}
```

> ```
> echo $items->ware['title'];
> echo $items->title;
> echo $items['title'];
> ```

отдают ошибку `Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: There is no column "ware" in`
и `atal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type MyItem as array in`

Помогите правильно запросить данные.

Спасибо!

Comment: Смотрите документацию или реализацию класса MyItem, как он предполагает отдавать данные.

Comment: Добавил `class MyItem` в вопрос.

Comment: Ошибку отдало `Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: There is no column "data" in `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как видно по `var_dump`, вы рассматриваете объект класса `MyItem`. Соответственно то что выводит `var_dump` может быть, а может и не быть способом достичь желаемые данные. Свойство `data` однозначно отмечено как `protected` и потому снаружи будет недоступно.

У класса `MyItem` есть два геттера: метод `only` и магический метод `__get`. Приключений добавляет то что на верхнем уровне вашего `data` - числовой массив. Поэтому обращаться к нему требуется именно как к числу. Синтаксически корректно это пишется так:

```
$obj = new MyItem([0=> ['title' => 'bar']]);
var_dump($obj->{0}['title']);
```

Либо через `only` достать весь элемент

```
var_dump($obj->only([0]));
```

Comment: Спасибо! Экземпляр класса MyItem у меня есть `return new MyItem($response);`, я забыл его добавить, сейчас добавил в вопрос. К сожалению, пока ничего у меня не получилось.

Comment: Включите error_reporting в единственно адекватный для разработки E_ALL. title у вас немного глубже.

Comment: если с новой попытки не заблудился в скобках - для вашего объекта будет`$items->{0}['ware']['title']`

Comment: Не заблудились, огромное вам спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```
// 1. Создаем экземпляр класса MyItem, на вход передаем данные (тестовые)
$items = new MyItem([
    "firstField" => 1,
    "secondField" => 2,
]);

// 2. Выводим в консоль поле firstField
print_r($items->only(["firstField"]));
```

Вывод в консоль:

```
Array
(
    [firstField] => 1
)
```

Получить значение можно также:

```
print_r($items->__get("firstField"));
```

Вывод в консоль:

```
1
```

Comment: Спасибо! Экземпляр класса MyItem у меня есть, я забыл его добавить, сейчас добавил в вопрос. К сожалению, пока ничего у меня не получилось.

Comment: $obj = new MyItem([0 => ['title' => 'bar']]); print_r($obj->{0}['title']); Такой пример выводит в консоле строку bar. Версия PHP при этом используется 7.0